# ng-model not updating $scope object from input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I have an edit form for updating answers in a forum:

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
    ...
    <div ng-show="answer.editMode" class="card pam">
        <edit-answer-form
            answer="answer"
        ></edit-answer-form>
   </div>
</div>
```

The edit answer form is as below:

```
{{answer.body}} <!--This appears on screen fine-->
<form ng-submit=editAnswer() method="POST">
    <input type="text" ng-model="answer.body" />
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

The Javascript for the directive is:

```
app.directive('editAnswerForm', function() {

var editAnswerController = ['$scope', 'flashMessageService', 'answerService', '$log', function($scope, flashMessageService, answerService, $log) {

    var logger = $log.getInstance('editAnswerFormDirective');

    $scope.editAnswer = function() {
        logger.info("Edited answer to send to service ", $scope.answer);
        answerService.editAnswer($scope.answer).then(function success(response) {
            flashMessageService.flashMessageSuccess("Your answer has been edited");
        }, function error(response) {
            flashMessageService.flashMessageError("Error editing answer");
            logger.error("Error editing answer: ", response);
        })
    };
}];

return {
    // restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/angular/app/answer/editAnswer.html',
    controller: editAnswerController,
    scope: {
        answer: '='
    }
}
});
```

The `$scope.answer` is being passed to the directive fine (the answer will appear on screen when putting `{{answer.xxx}}` on the screen). However in the form, the `answer.body` value is not present, nor does it update the model when writing into the input field, or logging out the values when submitting the form.

I have a similar directive/form for updating questions and that's working fine. The only difference is the answer is in a `ng-repeat`. Could it be something to do with this?

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Declare $scope.answer = {} in your controller

Comment: I tried that - it gets rid of the original answer if I do that, as the directive is updating the "original" scope (the one that comes from the parent controller). Also this wasnt needed when editing questions :/ Thanks

Comment: Please add a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/)

Comment: @MC123 this plunker works just find for me [https://plnkr.co/edit/qmpaTp?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/qmpaTp?p=preview). Check it out

Comment: @Ero Yeah I'm struggling to reproduce the issue on Plunkr :/

Comment: I've put the code in Github temporarily:

Comment: I've put the code in Github temporarily: https://github.com/mattcopas/forum-stackoverflow-example The files causing the error are https://github.com/mattcopas/forum-stackoverflow-example/blob/master/ui/angular/app/answer/editAnswer.html https://github.com/mattcopas/forum-stackoverflow-example/blob/master/ui/angular/app/answer/editAnswerFormDirective.js https://github.com/mattcopas/forum-stackoverflow-example/blob/master/ui/angular/app/question/question.html